# How to conditionally select a field from joined tables in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SELECT 
    title, 
    description, 
    status, 
    task.user_id AS creatorUserId, 
    (SELECT user.nickname FROM user WHERE user.id = task.user_id) AS creatorUserNickname,
    GROUP_CONCAT(user.id, "," ,user.nickname SEPARATOR ";") as responsibleUsers
FROM task JOIN task_user ON task.id = task_user.task_id
JOIN user ON task_user.user_id = user.id
GROUP BY title, description, status, creatorUserId, creatorUserNickname;
```

The query above works, but I wonder if it's possible to get the same result without a subquery.

I have a **task table** with **user_id column** for the user who created the task, and a **user table** with user data, like **nickname**.

Then there's a **task_user table** maping users assigned to the task.

My confusion lies on how to get different nicknames: one corresponding to **task.user_id**, the creator, and the others from **task_user.user_id**, the assignees.

The query below does't work, with creatorUserId and creatorUserNickname being repeated on responsibleUsers field, resulting in multiple rows for a single task.

```
SELECT 
    title, 
    description, 
    status, 
    task.user_id AS creatorUserId, 
    user.nickname AS creatorUserNickname,-- this user is referenced in task.user_id
    GROUP_CONCAT(user.id,"," ,user.nickname SEPARATOR ";") as responsibleUsers -- these in task_user.user_id
FROM task JOIN task_user ON task.id = task_user.task_id 
JOIN user ON task_user.user_id = user.id OR task.user_id = user.id
GROUP BY title, description, status, creatorUserId, creatorUserNickname;
```

Is there a way to select different **user.nickname** based on which table is referencing their ***id*** ?

Many thanks!

Comment: You have to join the user table twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need 2 joins to `user`.
The 1st to return the creator's details and the 2nd to return the users assigned to the task:

```
SELECT 
    t.title, 
    t.description, 
    t.status, 
    u1.user_id AS creatorUserId, 
    u1.nickname AS creatorUserNickname,
    GROUP_CONCAT(u2.id, ',' , u2.nickname SEPARATOR ';') AS responsibleUsers
FROM task t 
INNER JOIN task_user tu ON t.id = tu.task_id 
INNER JOIN user u1 ON t.user_id = u1.id 
INNER JOIN user u2 ON tu.user_id = u2.id 
GROUP BY t.title, t.description, t.status, creatorUserId, creatorUserNickname;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would actually suggest that you write the query as:

```
SELECT t.title, t.description, t.status, 
       t.user_id as creatorUserId, u.nickname as creatorUserNickname,
       (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(u.id, ',', u.nickname SEPARATOR ';)
        FROM task_users tu JOIN
             users u
             ON tu.user_id = u.user_id
        WHERE tu.task_id = t.id
       ) as responsibleUsers
FROM task t JOIN
     user u
     ON t.user_id = u.id ;
```

This avoids the outer aggregation -- which should improve performance.  It also includes all tasks, even those with no responsible users.  I'm guessing that is a good thing.